# Managing NPCs in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good time of day, such a question is how to create an NPC that will, for example, extract resources, that is, it will go from one object to another and perform actions there, and after completion, it will already go back to the starting position from where It started Its path? If possible, explain the principle for managing multiple units. And are there any "plugins" sharpened for this?

Answer (score 1):

your question is too broad and ambiguous. There are too many principles tied to this behaviour.

For pathfinding, depending on your project, you can use

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html

or if your project is a simpler 2D one, you can use an A* Grid Path instead.

For the npc behaviour, a simple state machine would suffice. I would suggest looking up CodeMonkey, who has great videos on this.
Check out:

Simple Enemy AI in Unity (State Machine, Find Target, Chase, Attack)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db0KWYaWfeM